# Another rust generics exercise

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a Monad like trait in Rust. Mostly just for fun and to get familiar with the type system. I'm pretty sure I will not be able to fully implement a Monad trait due to the lack of "higher kinds" as explained in this [reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1a57pw/haskeller_playing_with_rust_a_question_about/), but I want to see how close I can get. For some reason I can't get this code to compile. Seems like it should. Can someone explain why?

```
trait Monad<T> {
    fn lift(val: T) -> Self;
}

struct Context<T>{ 
    val: T 
}

impl<T> Monad<T> for Context<T> {
    fn lift(x: T) -> Context<T> {
        Context{val: x}
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let c:Context<int> = Context<int>::lift(5i);
}
```

Comment: this question could be improved if you added the exact error message it gave you (it helps other people find it) :)

Comment: You are right, next time....I havent used rust much in the last few years, I wouldnt know where to start now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static methods defined in a trait must be called through it. So, you'd have:

```
let c: Context<int> = Monad::lift(5);
```